# Load from GCS to GBQ causes an internal BigQuery error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

My application creates thousands of "load jobs" daily to load data from Google Cloud Storage URIs to BigQuery and only a few cases causing the error:

> "Finished with errors. Detail: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 7916072"

The application is written on Python and uses libraries:

```
google-cloud-storage==1.42.0
google-cloud-bigquery==2.24.1
google-api-python-client==2.37.0
```

Load job is done by calling

```python
load_job = self._client.load_table_from_uri(
    source_uris=source_uri,
    destination=destination,
    job_config=job_config,
)
```

this method has a default param:

```
retry: retries.Retry = DEFAULT_RETRY,
```

so the job should automatically retry on such errors.

Id of specific job that finished with error:

```
"load_job_id": "6005ab89-9edf-4767-aaf1-6383af5e04b6"
"load_job_location": "US"
```

after getting the error the application recreates the job, but it doesn't help.

Subsequent failed job ids:

```
5f43a466-14aa-48cc-a103-0cfb4e0188a2
43dc3943-4caa-4352-aa40-190a2f97d48d
43084fcd-9642-4516-8718-29b844e226b1
f25ba358-7b9d-455b-b5e5-9a498ab204f7
...
```

Comment: Why do you execute so many `load jobs`, do you use `wildcards` ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun to keep data up to date for many service accounts owned by customers. Jobs are triggered by some business events.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message, Wait according to the back-off requirements described in the [BigQuery Service Level Agreement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla), then try the operation again.

If the error continues to occur, if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue. You can also try to reduce the frequency of this error by using [Reservations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reservations-intro).

For more information about the error messages you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages).